# How to update a single field in django?

Tags: django, django-models

How do I update a single field in django using html template?
I have an html page to add records. I need to make an html page only to update a single field of the model. How do I do that. And what should be the view function for it.

Answer (score 0):

It's really quite simple with [an `UpdateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview).

It takes care of building a generic ModelForm class for the model too.

```
class UpdateSomeFieldView(views.UpdateView):
    fields = ('some_field',)
    model = MyModel
```

For the template, all you really need there is a

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.errors }}
  <table>{{ form.as_table }}</table>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I am using html template. I am displaying data of all fields in that page but only want to be able to update one particular field.